# C:folding a line after a fixed column

Tags: c, eof, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am trying to write my solution for the KnR problem 1-22. Below is my code which I am not able to get why it's not working. It just prints the whole line that I typed, without folding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SPACE ' '
#define LIMIT 1024
#define BREAK 20
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0

int main(void) {
    /*base, is an offset from where the difference of current array position will be calculated*/
    int c,base=0,i,l_break=OFF;
    char s[LIMIT];
    for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        /*If break is on and space comes, turn the space into newline so that the line folds*/
        if(l_break==ON && c==SPACE) {
            c=='\n';
            base=i;
        }
        /*Breaking position is reached but not a blank position yet to break.*/
        if(((i-base)==BREAK) && c!=SPACE)
            l_break=ON;
        /*If user sends a newline explicitly(or space converted to newline above), reset the base*/
        if(c == '\n') {
            base=i;
            s[i] = c;
            l_break=OFF;
        } else
            s[i] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    /*Print the final sentence after processing*/
    i=0;
    printf("\n");
    while(s[i]!='\0') {
        printf("%c",s[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, when I send EOF (^D) it again comes to read ,then I need to send EOF again to break it off. Why its not breaking first time I send EOF.

Comment: ^D isn't EOF; typing it on a line by itself will cause your terminal to send an EOF, though.  If you have anything on the line, it will just clear the buffer.  Is that what's happening?

Comment: What if the current character is a tab? It's a space as well. Use e.g. [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) to find out if a character is a "space".

Comment: @CarlNorum Somehow I'm not very clear what you are saying above. But if I am getting it right what you are saying, then it shouldn't break when I do ctrl+D second time as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c=='\n';` should be `c = '\n';` - Haven't checked to ensure that is the only issue...

Comment: You saved my day.. that was the problem.!! though the EOF thing I still need to check..   I have a telephonic interview in few hours :D

Comment: If I've solved the problem you accept the answer. Good luck with the interview!